# Resharper - How to stop line breaks with expressions

Tags: c#, resharper, line-breaks, code-formatting, code-cleanup

I've tried all of the obvious Resharper settings I could but to no avail.

This is the code Resharper produces:

```
   var customer = CustomerBuilder.Build(
            c => c
                .WithJobProgram(
                    i => i
                        .WithId(programId)));
```

This is the code formatted the way we need it to:

```
   var customer = CustomerBuilder.Build(c => c
                     .WithJobProgram(i => i
                         .WithId(programId)));
```

How do I stop Resharper from breaking the expressions (c => c) onto new lines?

Comment: you can try 
`ReSharper | Options -> Code Editing | C# | Formatting style | Line breaks and wrapping -> LineWrapping | Wrap long lines`